# Convert Standard sql Expression To Legacy (Bytes to Timestamp)

Tags: sql, timestamp, google-bigquery, byte

I currently have the following standard SQL expression:

```
TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(NET.IPV4_TO_INT64(substr(FROM_BASE64(replace(replace('user_id',"-","+"),"_","/")),0,4)))
```

But I need it written in legacy SQL.

I have gotten this far:

```
LEFT(FROM_BASE64(REPLACE(Replace('V95182FFZAAnIlNQ',"-","+"),"_","/")),4)
```

but can't manage to convert from BYTES to a timestamp.

Comment: Well, that's definitly not *Standard SQL*

Comment: Why are you trying to convert it to legacy SQL?

Comment: To nest into another query which is written in legacy sql

Comment: you should go the other way around, legacy queries should be ported to the standard version!